# Physical screen dimensions and resolution options don't match

Tags: resolution, thinkpad

I recently purchased a Lenovo T510 refurbished laptop (Windows 7) and I'm trying to figure out the native resolution and best resolution setting.

What's puzzling me is that the aspect ratio of the physical screen (approx. 344 x 193 mm, as measured by me) is 16:9. And yet the only resolution settings provided are: 1280 x 1024 (5:4), 1280 x 800 (16:10), 1024 x 768 (4:3) and 800 x 600 (4:3). Obviously the 1280 x 800 matches most closely, but it's still off.

In fact I went to [the Lenovo site for the T510](http://www.lenovo.com/us/en/PDFs/ThinkPad_T410_T510_Datasheet.html) to view the specs, and it lists the screen as having a resolution of 1366 x 768 (confirming my 16:9 physical measurement).

If it's any relevance, display field shows "Generic Non-PnP Monitor on Standard VGA Graphics Adapter."

So my question is, if the physical screen is 16:9, why am I not being given an option to set my resolution to a 16:9 ratio, and in particular the native 1366 x 768 dimensions listed on the Lenovo site?

Comment: Sounds like your drivers are not installed correctly - before you go any further, download and install the latest video (and if available, monitor) drivers from lenovo's page for that model.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks very much. I'll give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

When you load a default copy of Windows on existing hardware, the built in Windows drivers have a limited set of resolutions. Go to [Lenovo's Support Site](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t510?menu-id=laptop,_desktop,_tablet,_workstation_and_thinkserver_support) and get the drivers for your laptop.